# MySQL table locking issue in Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, django, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are hosting MySQL database in Amazon RDS platform. We see a lot of deadlock issues due to locking. I am trying to understand the deadlock dump report which roughly describes the affected transactions & no of locks etc. Following is such a trace:

```
2017-12-14 09:00:21 2ba3a5758700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1297355720, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 7 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 9198894, OS thread handle 0x2ba0b33da700, query id 5198593130
```

In the above trace, the 4th line says - '`mysql tables in use 1, locked 1`'. What does 'locked 1' mean? Does it mean the concerned table is fully locked during the transaction?

We are not explicitly locking the table. We use Django @transaction.atomic at certain places, but no explicit Table locking is there in our code.

Please help me understand how can I debug the Table locking issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check all places that have @transaction.atomic, and see whether they modify tables in the same order in every such code block. If not - it's the most likely place the deadlocks are occurring.